# HTML - button - onclick in search bar

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I'm looking for a solution for the following: I have a search bar with the following code:

```
<input autofocus class="form-control" style="width:40%" type="search" id="myInput" placeholder="Enter keywords here...">
```

I have several buttons as such:

```
<input type="button" value="Banana">
<input type="button" value="Pear">
```

What would I need to add in order, so when you click on the Banana button, the word Banana is pasted in the search bar (input id="myInput").

I know you need an onclick="" in the button input and a javascript to paste the text, but what is the function?

EDIT:

I currently already have a listener event:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  if (document.getElementById("myInput").value.length > 1) {
    document.getElementById("header").className = "hideHeader";
  } else {
    ContactsearchFX();
    document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('input', ContactsearchFX);
  }
});
```

How do I integrate this solution:

HTML

> ```
> <button onclick="addval('Banana')">Banana</button>
> <button onClick="addval('Pear')">Pear</button>
> ```

Javascript

```
 function setValue(name){
   document.getElementById("myInput").value = name;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the value of the button to your input text. 
First you create a function to handle the click on your button, once that is done you pass the value of the button to the input field.

```js
const clickButtonHandler = (evt) => { 
 document.querySelector('.form-control').value = evt.value;
}
```

```html
<input autofocus class="form-control" style="width:40%" type="search" id="myInput" placeholder="Enter keywords here...">

<input type="button" onclick="clickButtonHandler(this)" value="Banana">
<input type="button" onclick="clickButtonHandler(this)" value="Pear">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This did work, however I have some other scripts, so I couldn't use this solution. However, this is not something I did mention, so I did want to express my gratefulness.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fix it:

```
<input type="button" id="fruit" value="Banana">

document.getElementById("fruit").addEventListener("click", function(){
       document.getElementById("myInput").value = this.value;
});
```

Comment: This was the most simple solution for me, which didn't interfere with my code, but did what it needed to do. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to integrate this with the listening event (I have placed the code above in the inital post. TIA!)

Comment: yes you can also do that please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input autofocus class="form-control" style="width:40%" type="search" id="myInput" placeholder="Enter keywords here...">
<button onclick="addval('Banana')">Banana</button>
<button onClick="addval('Apple')">Apple</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function addval(e){
   var input = document.getElementById('myInput');
   input.value += ' '+e; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("myInput").value = "Banana";
}
```

And for the button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Banana</button>
```

Comment: This was working as well, however because I have about 15 buttons, this would create a lot of scripts. Nevertheless thank you.